# Hide image while loading new source

Tags: react-native

I've implemented a React Native component which shows an image loaded from a remote server. The user can swipe the image out of the screen in order to navigate to the next image which is again loaded from the remote server. While loading of the second image, the old image is still visible on the screen.

I want the old image to disappear while loading the next image. Any hint how to achieve this?

Prop `defaultSource` only works for initial render (showing the first image) but not consecutive images. So I guess React reuses the Image under the hood. I've played around with `onLoadStart` and `onLoadEnd` but I don't know how to reset the source of the old image.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: A basic way is to store the current image in a state, say currentImage, and updating this when loading a new image, forcing a re-render.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a unique `key` prop to each image. It can be a number or a string. That will prevent React from re-using the elements.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for! As soon as the key changes while re-rendering the image, the old image disappears immediately.